# Voro-Noise shader, understanding iqnoise and hash function

Tags: glsl, interpolation, noise, voronoi, procedural-generation

I recently became aware of Cell noise based procedural generation techniques.  I came [across this website](https://thebookofshaders.com/12/) which explained the concept of cellular (or Worley) noise quite well.  Upon further reading, the author links to [Voro-Noise](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/voronoise/voronoise.htm) in which Inigo Quilez (the author of Voro-Noise) proceeds to give a rough overview of his shader.  I don't understand a few parts of it however.  Why is the hash function created as such:

```
vec3 hash3( vec2 p ) {
    vec3 q = vec3( dot(p,vec2(127.1,311.7)), 
                   dot(p,vec2(269.5,183.3)), 
                   dot(p,vec2(419.2,371.9)) );
    return fract(sin(q)*43758.5453);
}
```

I'm not sure the significance of the numbers nor why sin is used here, it doesn't appear to be explained on his page.

I also don't understand why there is a need to iterate over 25 points instead of the 9 used in previous examples.

```
for (int j=-2; j<=2; j++) {
        for (int i=-2; i<=2; i++) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

changing the '2' and '-2' in each loop to '1' and '-1' seems to create artifacts and change the nature of the blur.

Why are we taking the dot product of the distance difference and itself? (which I guess finds the length of the vector squared?)

```
    vec2  r = g - f + o.xy;
    float d = dot(r,r);
```

And finally, while the author of voro-noise goes into what the power function is, he didn't really go into detail into why this works. why do we create K in this way (the author talks about raising smooth step to the power of 1, but I don't see that being a possibility here) Why do we create `ww`, multiply it by the offsets z component and why do we divide `va` by `wt`?  I understand we add some sort of interpolation value between all points based on their contribution, but I just don't understand why the interpolator is constructed as is

```
float k = 1.0+63.0*pow(1.0-v,4.0);
float va = 0.0;
float wt = 0.0;

        ...
        float ww = pow( 1.0-smoothstep(0.0,1.414,sqrt(d)), k );
        va += o.z*ww;
        wt += ww;
...
return va/wt;
```

How does the hermitian interpolator (`smoothstep` here) help here? From what I understand we are passing 0, sqrt(2) and the sqrt(length of difference vector) here.

Comment: Isn't it just an approximation?

Comment: @Betterdev Gonna have to be more specific there bud.

Comment: A weighted voronoi diagram is defined as the euklidian distance substracted with the weight.